# Express $\sinh(x+y)$ and $\cosh(x+y)$ in terms of $\cosh(x), \sinh(x), \cosh(y), \sinh(y)$

Tags: integration

I don't know if my answer is ok or not for this question below:

Use the definitions $$\cosh(x)=\frac12\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right), \hspace{0.2in}\sinh(x)=\frac12\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$$

to express $\sinh(x+y)$ and $\cosh(x+y)$ in terms of $\cosh(x), \sinh(x), \cosh(y)$, and $\sinh(y)$.

$\cosh(x+y) = \cosh(x)\cosh(y) + \sinh(a)\sinh(b)$
and substitute $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ and $\sinh(y)$ and $\cosh(y)$ by using $\cosh^2(x) + \sinh^2(x) = 1$

I just want to know if my way is on the right track or not. Thanks guy :) 
If someone have the final answer, please share. So i can re-check with my once :D (sorry , i am not that good of math )

Comment: Theres no $a$ and $b$. But, you can easily google sum identities for sinh and cosh ot check your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we will use the facts $$\cosh x + \sinh x = e^x, \cosh x - \sinh x = e^{-x} $$ repeatedly.

$$\begin{align}2\cosh(x+y)&=e^{x+y} + e^{-x -y}\\
 &= e^xe^y + e^{-x}e^{-y}\\
&=(\cosh x + \sinh x)(\cosh y + \sinh y) +(\cosh x - \sinh x)(\cosh y - \sinh y)\\
&= 2\left(\cosh x\cosh y+\sinh x \sinh y\right)\end{align}$$

dividing out by $2$ gives $$\cosh(x+y)= \cosh x\cosh y+\sinh x \sinh y$$

similarly you can show $$\sinh(x+y)= \sinh x\cosh y+\sinh y \cosh x$$

Comment: Hi, I am confuse of the value 2 in '' 2cosh(x+y) ''

Comment: i got it... Thanks. Have a nice day :)